# Hide form after submit (but after bringing it back?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a hard time making this form submit twice. What do I mean? When I click on submit, the form (on `General.js`) is hidden and it renders another component (`DisplayGeneral.js`) displaying the user's input. Then I added a button to bring back the form so the user can edit the information, the problem is that it doesn't toggle again when I click on the form button, you know? What am I missing here? Please, I appreciate any help.

**General.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../style/style.css';
import DisplayGeneral from './DisplayGeneral';

class General extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      showing: true,
      isEditing: true,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { showing } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      showing: !showing,
    });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { isEditing } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !isEditing,
    });
  }

  form = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className='generalForm'>
          <label htmlFor='nameInput' className='row'>
            Name:{' '}
            <input
              type='text'
              name='name'
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              id='nameInput'
            />
          </label>
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderGeneral() {
    const {
      isEditing,
      name,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {isEditing ? (
          <div>
            <DisplayGeneral
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              name={name}

            />
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Edit</button> // button added
          </div>
        ) : (
          this.form()
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { showing } = this.state;

    return (
      <section className='divGeneral'>
        <div className='sectionTitle'>
          <h1>General Information</h1>
        </div>
        {showing ? this.form() : this.renderGeneral()}
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default General;
```

**DisplayGeneral.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DisplayGeneral extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;

    return (
      <section className='renderedSection'>
        <article>
          <span className='spanArtc'>Name: </span>
          {name}
        </article>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayGeneral;
```

Comment: Are you looking to submit the form again, or simply toggle the showing state? You don't have any code that handles form submission, it simply togges it on or off atm.

Comment: yes I'm just toggling it. but I can managed to toggle it twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to toggle the form you can keep only one flag `isEditing` and change it to true, if you want to show the form and false for showing information.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../style/style.css';
import DisplayGeneral from './DisplayGeneral';

class General extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      isEditing: true,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isEditing: false,
    });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isEditing: true,
    });
  }

  form = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className='generalForm'>
          <label htmlFor='nameInput' className='row'>
            Name:{' '}
            <input
              type='text'
              name='name'
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              id='nameInput'
            />
          </label>
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderGeneral() {
    const { name } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <DisplayGeneral handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} name={name} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Edit</button> // button added
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { isEditing } = this.state;

    return (
      <section className='divGeneral'>
        <div className='sectionTitle'>
          <h1>General Information</h1>
        </div>
        {isEditing ? this.form() : this.renderGeneral()}
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default General;
```